# Unique Ids in Join table symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities products and categories, i have successfully created a many-many relationship b/w them, as a result a new table has been created which looks like :

```
┌────────────────┐         ┌───────────────────┐         ┌────────────────┐
|  products      |         | product_categories|         |     categories |
├────────────────┤         ├───────────────────┤         ├────────────────┤
| id#            ├---------┤ product_id        |    ┌----┤ id#            |
| --             |         | cat_id            ├----┘    | --             |
| --             |         |                   |         |                |
└────────────────┘         └───────────────────┘         └────────────────┘
```

---

### Categories

```
  /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Products", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $product;
```

**Products**

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="categories", inversedBy="product")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_categories",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="cat_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
protected $category;
```

Now i want product and cat_id to be unique in product_categories table. how it can be done ?

Comment: targetEntity="categories" should be upper case. But I don't think that's cause the problem. Could you paste result of "SHOW CREATE TABLE product_categories" from your mysql console (I didn't ask, but I assume that you use mysql right?)?

Comment: sure, the only thing i am unsure about is, will i have to make the composite key at DB (mysql) level manually or annotation will handle it ???

Comment: Doctrine should handle it.

Comment: Actually, I have created the entities and tables manually and have just used the command to generate getters and setters.Now, I have created a composite key constraint to product_category table and have added a try catch code to handle duplicate entries. Now Everything I wanted is achieved. is that the right way to do it ??

Comment: No, it's terrible idea! Use doctrine to handling your database schema. I've edited my answer to show how you should do that. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

If you specify your many-to-many relation implicitly for example through an annotation (`@ManyToMany`) Doctrine will create composite primary key consists with both fields: product_id and cat_id, so you have a guarantee that it would be unique.

If you specify your many-to-many associations explicitly through additional entity (let's say `ProductCategories`) you could just add UniqueEntity constraint.

[UniqueEntity constraint documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)

An example with annotations:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * (...)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"product_id", "cat_id"})
 */
class ProductCategories {
    // (...)
```

**edit:**

In addition make sure that you've generated your database correctly. You should use Doctrine's commands to do that (don't do it manually!):

```
php -f ./app/console doctrine:database:drop
php -f ./app/console doctrine:database:create
php -f ./app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

In that way, based on your entities, Doctrine will create appropriate db schema. If you will change anything in future (in your entities), you'll be able to just update your schema:

```
php -f ./app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

(with most of above commands you can also add `--dump-sql` argument which results in showing only sql instead of changing your database)

Comment: well, i have generated relations through annotaions but unfortunately, its accepting duplicate entries ..

Comment: Hmm, it's weird. I've used ManyToMany a lot in many projects from Symfony 2.1 to 2.3, ant it always creates composite primary key which forbid duplicate entries. Could you show how you define this associations? Maybe there is sth wrong