# Validate UniqueEntity for One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table [Symfony2]

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

**I have 2 mapped entities**,

Box

```
class Box{
    //[...]
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Candy", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"power" = "DESC"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="box_candies",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="box_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="candy_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     */
    private $candies;
}
```

And Candy

```
class Candy
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
    //[...]
}
```

As you can see, this is **One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table** association. Box can "store" candies, but Candy knows nothing about Box (where is).

Now I have page where I can make **candy** and there is form and standard `isValid()` and after that:

```
$box->addCandy($candy);
$entity_manager->persist($candy);
$entity_manager->persist($box);
$entity_manager->flush();
```

*Now, where is my problem?*

I would like to Box can store **only** unique candies (by **name**), that means Box can store Candy objects with names **"Choco" and "Orange"** but can't **"Mayonnaise" and "Mayonnaise"**

When making candy i can't validate with `UniqueEntity` constraint because the candy does not know about the box. I thought about `Callback` validator for Box or create own Constraint but i think it's better to ask:

**How should I do it?**

Comment: Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18894942/1307183) - you should put a `UniqueEntity` on the `name` field of your Candy entity.  When you are doing the `@ManyToMany` annotation on your Box entity, Doctrine will automatically treat that as a composite primary key for you and enforce uniqueness exactly as you want.

Comment: Nope, In my case `name` is not unique value

Comment: Why isn't it a unique value?

Comment: In my case `Candy` exist in many `Boxes` but Candy name is Unique for every `Box` but not for all Boxes at the same time

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that - but Candy is its own entity, completely unrelated to anything with Boxes, correct?  So you would never have 2 entries for 'Chocolate' in your candy table.  Then each box would simply link to whatever candies are in them with the many-to-many relationship you already have.

Comment: If I understand it correct - yes. I would never have 2 'Chocolate' in 1 Box but Box1 can have and Box2 too but separately

Comment: Right - so you can put `UniqueEntity` on the `name` field of your Candy entity, and then your `@ManyToMany` annotation will handle the uniqueness for each Box for you automatically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99979/discussion-between-griva-and-jason-roman).

Answer (score 0):

Answer is late but it may help someone so this is solution I implemented:

In my case I can create `Candy` only in one place via form so finally I decided to create additional special validation for that case in my controller/service.

Simply speaking I made code checking the name in my own way and when it's invalid, form just trow `Error` to prevent creation. I want to emphasize that this is a little dirty solution and also it is not scalable because you have to remember always to add it in correct place if you create Candy in other places.

```
    // special unique name validation
    $candy_name = $form->get('name')->getData();
    if($candy_name){
        $found_candy = $box->getCandyByName($candy_name);
        if($found_candy){
            $error = new FormError( $this->get('translator')->trans("candy.name.exist", array(), "validators") );
            $form->get('name')->addError($error);
        }
    }
```

Anyway it worked but depending on your case, [Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) can be way better solution or even simple `UniqueEntity` constraint.