# Doctrine - Query One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table association from inversed side

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

### **My target is:**

Create universal association where first entity *(eg. Category)* can be used many times for other Objects *(eg. Post, Article)*

**Example**

Post has categories and Article has categories, but Article and Post are totally different entities. *(connection is not possible for both at the same time)*

---

### **Mapping example:**

Post

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class Post
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category")
     * @JoinTable(name="post_categories",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     */
    private $categories;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories= new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Article

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class Article
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category")
     * @JoinTable(name="article_categories",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     */
    private $categories;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories= new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Category

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class Category
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

As you can see this is One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table association.
Now with this I **can** query for single `Post` categories and `Article` categories but Category dont know about Post or Article. This is nice because I can use `Category` repeatedly.

---

### **Where is a problem?**

I need load **ALL** `Posts` or `Articles` which contain single `Category` or `Categories`.

**Example**

We have 20 Posts with Category named `"symfony"` *(id:2)* and 10  with with Category named `"doctrine"` *(id:3)*. Now i need query to load all Posts with category `"doctrine"`

```
findPostsByCategoryId( $id );
// findPostsByCategoryId( 3 );
```

**OR** all Posts with **both** categories

```
findPostsByCategories( Array $array );
// findPostsByCategories( array(2,3) );
```

### How can i do this?

I need solution for this case or solution to achieve my goal.
Each tip is appreciated.

*P.S. I have other related problem with this mapping described here*

[Validate UniqueEntity for One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523032/validate-uniqueentity-for-one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table-symfony2)

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track - are you getting errors or not receiving information you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, errors but i cant create valid query without warnings and "information you're looking for" :)

Comment: Could you post the actual warnings you are getting?

Comment: For example: "Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias." But i think even without the error, my query wouldn't load what i want

Comment: Your best route is going to be creating custom repository functions that use the QueryBuilder or DQL to get what you need.  It also sounds like you might be selecting from the wrong root alias, which is difficult to determine without seeing the full code that you are posting.

Comment: I try DQL and Repository but this is problem - I don't know how create valid query. In addition i think this is universal question - i created this "Category example" to show general problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless I'm misreading your question this seems pretty simple:

Get all posts with a specific category:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('p')
    ->from('SomeBundle:Post', 'p')
    ->join('p.categories', 'c')
    ->where('c.id = :categoryId')
    ->setParameter('categoryId', $categoryId)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Get all posts with a range of categories:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('p')
    ->from('SomeBundle:Post', 'p')
    ->join('p.categories', 'c')
    ->where($qb->expr()->in('c.id', ':categoryIds'))
    ->setParameter('categoryIds', $categoryIds) // array of ids
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```